# How does a transaction complete in bitocin?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, bitcode, blockchain.info-api

If B is transferring bitcoin to C then when will be C receive the bitcoin? Is that after all the miners add that transaction into their local ledger? (I think it is time-consuming and what will happen if some miners are not adding?)
Now, if some miners are finding transaction invalid, while some find it valid so what will be the scenario in that case? When will be C receive the bitcoin?

Answer (score 1):

The blockchain is a public ledger, so B isn't sending the transaction to just C, B is announcing it to everyone in the public network that i am sending bitcoin to C. So everyone in the network can see this transaction and now has to wait to be included in a block.

Miners create blocks of transactions, in every 10 minutes a new block is included into the ledger.and they have to create them in such a way that the rest of the network will accept them. One of the requirements is that the transactions in the block are all valid transactions. So yes, miners will validate that B has send bitcoins to C before they add the transaction to a block.

As all the full nodes in the bitcoin blockchain knows the currect state of bitcoins hold by B, they can easily verify the validity of the transaction.

Note: Each node in the blockchain either accepts or rejects a transaction.

Here's details you may want to have a look

```
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules#.22tx.22_messages
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when C will receive amount./bitcoin? When all miners accept it? and consider there are 10,000 miners then all 10,000 minors have to accept it. Won't it take time?

Comment: And according to your answer, it seems that each transaction will be completed in 10 mins.

Comment: Each 10 minutes is created a block. Your transaction could be inside that block or not. So, if it isn't inside the block, you should wait

Comment: @PJR No each transaction is not completed within 10 mins, blocks are created every 10 mins. These blocks are then get validated and as number of blocks on top the current block get added transaction start getting confirmation. e.g. If 10 blocks are get added after the Block in which B transaction is included. then number of confirmation will be 10. Also once a miner mathematically verifies a block or transaction, it will send it to all the miners in the network to cross verify the solution. If more then 51% of miners agrees on the solution that will be treated as a valid transaction

Answer (score 0):

> when will be C receive the bitcoin? Is that after all the minors add
>   that transaction into their local ledger?

Each minor is trying to mine a block. When someone mines a block, the block is distributed along the network. So, every miner get that block. In a block, there would be some transactions.

However, another block could be mined at the same time. A miner who receives more than one block at the same time will continue mining along a branch. So, after some time, one of the branches will win.

Because of that, a transaction is valid when there are 100 more new blocks (I'm not sure if they are 100 or less) on top of that block.

> what will happen if some minors are not adding?

After some time, all the minors will reach consensus about the branch and all of them will have the same blocks.

> if some minors are finding transaction invalid, while some find it
>   valid so what will be the scenario in that case?

When a miner receives a block, verifies if all transactions are valid. If not, it sends a message to the rest of the miners to tell them that the block is invalid.

The result of a  transaction (valid or invalid) is the same to all the members of the network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when C will receive amount./bitcoin? When all miners accept it? and consider there are 10,000 miners then all 10,000 minors have to accept it. Won't it take time?

Comment: C receives inmediately the amount, but it couldn't spend it until a 100 blocks are created above it. All the miners have the same chain, so at the end everyone validates and accepts it. I don't know how much time takes a transaction to be accepted by every peer, however, it won't be valid until the 100 blocks are created above it.